# Working with authentication and AngularJS as well as SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, authentication, active-directory

I am working on creating a website for my web systems class in which I will be implementing a login platform. The website after becoming authenticated the user will be able to send messages to other users, I will be implementing SignalR to perform the real-time messaging.

I want to create a system that within AngularJS I can call a C# backend provide a username and password and authenticate. I would also at the same time like to use SignalR's role based authentication to ensure my methods are secure.

Example:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] 
public class AdminAuthHub : Hub 
{ 
}
```

Currently I've written my own code to accept a username and password and hash it and store the hash value. However, I don't want to reinvent the wheel here. I want to use a Microsoft based authentication system because I am working within a C# backend and SignalR technology.

I am currently hosting using Microsoft Azure and that works and all but I am eventually going to be switching to a locally hosted Windows Server I maintain. I have heard about using Active Directory but have never worked with it and would have to do extensive setup to get a fresh server ready for that.

My overall question is what path do I go? Also if I go the strictly Microsoft everything way, is setting up active directory simple on Windows Server 2016? During my research I found that there is a ASP.NET method of authenticating a user against a SQL Server database. Would this method be preferable because the system can be used outside of ASP.NET and the data is in a form that I've worked with before?

Do I write my own custom authenticate logic, accepting username and password and hashing and using my own tables and databases. Then within the SignalR side of things find a way of setting the user variable and setting their role from my database. Then simply performing a check at the beginning of each method call.

Comment: What ASP.Net framework are you using? 4.5.2? Core?
You don't need to use Active Directory - https://www.asp.net/identity would be a good place to start.

For AngularJS 1/2? You probably want to take a look at oAuth2 and OpenId connect to handle Authentication.

Comment: The only reason I mentioned AngularJs is because there may be portions of the website that aren't connected to SignalR that still need to perform an authenticated function. Such as simply changing a setting about the account. However could I just write Angular that sends that data to the server and the server determines if the user is authenticated? C# backend running in an Asmx file. I know its old and outdated.

Comment: I would suggest taking some time to read about different web technologies. What it seems that you are trying to achieve is a semi "static" website, hooked into SignalR, I believe you can achieve anything that you are trying to with ASP.Net MVC. "https://app.pluralsight.com/player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m3-identity&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals" might be a good place to start.

Comment: I am not entirely new to website and web tech, however I am not professionally educated in regards to web tech. I am currently rocking a default.aspx page on my landing and then within the landing page the navbar is on it as well as a div that uses angularjs ng-include to load other pages within it.

Comment: That's fine, everyone has to start somewhere. ASPX pages are in an opinionated statement a thing of the past. If you run through a tutorial on MVC and WebAPI, you may find a lot more examples of things you are trying to achieve online.

Comment: The problem that I have run into in the past and even now when trying to develop websites using the MVC with visual studio is that when it creates this project for you it adds so much stuff that is just so confusing if this is the first time you have seen it. So I just created a demo website and literally I have no understanding of what is happening because it all looks so confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information on the internet about how to potentially approach some of those questions.

A quick google for "Angualr / Asp.net identity / signalr" returns a few resources that you may suite your needs, maybe not solely, but you should be able to combine some of the approaches.

Here a few links for you :

[SignalR Authorization using Web API Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662899/signalr-authorization-using-web-api-token)

https://logcorner.com/angular-js-token-based-authentication-using-asp-net-identity-and-asp-net-web-api/

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/884647/Web-app-using-Web-API-SignalR-and-AngularJS